# Main NSWindow shadow doesn't change like child windows

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, dropshadow

The primary window in my app is borderless:

```
[self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

From that window, I also open other child windows. When I click around between those other child windows I see the drop shadow of those child windows get darker/larger when that child window gets clicked and becomes the focused window. However, my main window's shadow doesn't change when it loses or gains focus. So, there isn't much user feedback to tell them that original primary window has become the focus again.

Do I need to override something in my borderless window subclass to enable the shadow changes? It has a shadow, it just doesn't get darker/larger when that window is the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The darker shadow is a behavior tied to the `NSTitledWindowMask` so I don't believe that you can actually get this using the `NSBorderlessWindowMask`.

Comment: Electron does it so must be possible.

Comment: Well, a lot can change in 5 years :)

Comment: I have a theory Electron does it by offseting the main view into the title area space. It should work, but then you cant customise the shape of the window. The only other way I can think of is insetting the main view and drawing a dropshadow your self, and forwarding mouse events to the underlying windows. Also might need to remove the inset on fullscreen. Puhh.